# How to call an xaml page from a window? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a beginner at WPF so it might be a silly question.

To call one page  from page, I have done something similar to the following code:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ProductsManagement.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

But now I have created a Window and when trying to execute the previous code an error is generated. Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

The error:

[image]

With solution:

[image]

Comment: A new window needs to be opened up and not navigated.

Comment: Already achieved. Thanks for write

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
NavigationWindow _navigationWindow = new NavigationWindow();

_navigationWindow.Height = this.Height;
_navigationWindow.Width = this.Width;
_navigationWindow.Show();

_navigationWindow.Navigate(new MyPageXML());
```

Comment: How is this different from what you originally had in the question?

Comment: I'm in a <Window ... and I want to call a <Page

Comment: This is the exact same code you originally had in the question.  So how does this answer the question?

Comment: But this did not work: NavigationService.Navigate (new Uri ("/ ProductsManagement.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: I will update an image in the question so that you evade the error

Comment: Ready, there you can see the differences